# How to extract anchor text/ words from every hyperlinks from pdf using python?

Tags: python, pypdf, pdfminer, pymupdf, pdf-extraction

I am trying to extract hyperlink present in each page with their anchor text from pdf using PymuPdf library. I am able to extract hyperlinks with their page numbers but couldn't able to extract anchor text/words for every hyperlinks.

Can anyone help me ?

***Here is the code***

```
import fitz # PyMuPDF

result = []

with fitz.open(file) as doc:

    for page_no in range(1, len(doc)+1):

        page = doc[page_no-1]

        for link in page.links():

            if "uri" in link:

                url = link["uri"]
                result.append([page_no, url])  

            else:
                pass
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you KJ for your response!....So it is not possible to extract the text which attached to the specific link? Actually that's what I have to do it in my use-case to extract all the possible text with their associated links from the PDF files.

Comment: So in my use-case I have to create a dataframe which consist of 3 columns (page_no, text_name, links) whenever I pass any PDF into my code. From the above code I can able to fetch page_no and links but no idea about how to extract text_name associated to those links.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the text within the link's "hot area", `link["from"]` like this:
`text = page.get_textbox(link["from"])`.

Also any other of the various `page.get_text()` variants can be used if you need more text detail (e.g. color, font, ...) by using the `clip` parameter. For example, `page.get_text("dict", clip=link["from"])` delivers a dictionary of the text under the link rectangle with font name, font size, font color and more.

Comment: Thank you so much Jorj for your solution, after using your code I can able to extract 'from' values like this :                                                               
for link : 1 => Rect(156.47000122070312, 258.22998046875, 202.99000549316406, 270.3800048828125)
     for link : 2 => Rect(209.63999938964844, 258.22998046875, 256.1600036621094, 270.3800048828125)                But after getting coordinates for those links how can I extract the text?

Comment: Not sure if I understand: just use `page.get_textbox(rect)` for every link rectangle `rect` of the links you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks Jorj...I went through your _Github_->https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities/tree/master/textbox-extraction ...which was really helpful. From the above solution you asked to use **page.get_textbox(link["from"])**  to extract link text coordinates and as I mentioned earlier I am getting **rect** values but after using **rect** values in **page.get_textbox(rect)** its showing empty string. However, when I am using **page.get_text("words")** from your _GithubRepo_ I am getting coordinates for each word and it really hard to find text coordinated for the attached link.

Comment: and using **page.first_annot.rect** its throwing error like this **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rect'**

Comment: Links in (Py-) MuPDF do not count as annots - although they technically (per PDF spec) are in fact annotations.
The reason for this is that MuPDF wants to provide 3 separate chains: one for links, one for annotations, one for fields.
So your `.first_annot.rect` will never take a link for this.

Comment: If you see no text if you extract from the link rect, the reason may be that that rectangle technically is too small - mostly the height is the problem. This is the fault of the software creating the link.
Solve this by increasing the extraction rect somewhat, for example take `link["from"] + (-5,-5,5,5)` which is a rectangle 5 pixels larger in every direction.

Comment: Thanks a ton **Jorj**....it helped...issue is resolved.

Answer (score -2):

This works best for me

```py
def extractPdfText(pdf_path):
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_path) # type: ignore
    text = ''
    for page_num in range(doc.page_count):
        page = doc[page_num]
        localText = page.get_text()
        for link in page.get_links():
            if 'uri' in link:
                linktext = page.get_textbox(link["from"])
                # if link not in text then add it else skip
                if link['uri'] not in localText and link['uri'].startswith('http'):
                    localText = localText.replace(linktext, f"{linktext} {link['uri']} ")                                
        text += localText       

    return text
```